# Why doesn't scipy.optimize.curve_fit fit the data?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I'm having some trouble using `curve_fit` to fit some curve. From visual inspection (and knowledge of the domain), the data is sinusoidal in nature. However, curve_fit does not match the data at all.

Here is my code, as I have it now:

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit as cf
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

xdata=np.arange(0.05,10.01,0.05)

ydata="""
0.4000752
0.4231248
0.4456256
0.4684008
0.4892552
0.5054448
0.5150488
0.5155976
0.5081888
0.4919992
0.4716936
0.4494672
0.4258688
0.4058376
0.3901968
0.3803184
0.3794952
0.3866296
0.400624
0.4201064
0.4428816
0.4656568
0.4873344
0.5032496
0.5120304
0.513128
0.5070912
0.492548
0.4730656
0.4522112
0.4297104
0.4085816
0.3926664
0.3866296
0.3825136
0.3885504
0.4030936
0.4228504
0.4448024
0.4656568
0.48706
0.5029752
0.5120304
0.5134024
0.5068168
0.4928224
0.47334
0.4502904
0.4269664
0.4063864
0.3904712
0.3811416
0.3797696
0.3866296
0.4000752
0.4203808
0.4434304
0.4662056
0.4895296
0.5057192
0.518616
0.5191648
0.5101096
0.4988592
0.5005056
0.460992
0.4310824
0.4096792
0.3934896
0.3808672
0.380044
0.3866296
0.4000752
0.4201064
0.4428816
0.4659312
0.4865112
0.5024264
0.5114816
0.513128
0.5068168
0.4933712
0.4738888
0.4519368
0.4288872
0.4072096
0.3912944
0.385532
0.3797696
0.3888248
0.4058376
0.42532
0.444528
0.4673032
0.4919992
0.50764
0.513128
0.5128536
0.5059936
0.4950176
0.4771816
0.4511136
0.4286128
0.407484
0.3912944
0.3819648
0.380044
0.3860808
0.3998008
0.4190088
0.4415096
0.4648336
0.4851392
0.5013288
0.5112072
0.5128536
0.5125792
0.4922736
0.47334
0.4533088
0.4305336
0.4099536
0.393764
0.381416
0.3792208
0.385532
0.3989776
0.4190088
0.4409608
0.4640104
0.4854136
0.502152
0.5112072
0.513128
0.5068168
0.492548
0.4736144
0.4516624
0.4291616
0.4077584
0.3921176
0.382788
0.3803184
0.3863552
0.4000752
0.4179112
0.4406864
0.4634616
0.4865112
0.5029752
0.5125792
0.5142256
0.5081888
0.4947432
0.4736144
0.4519368
0.4286128
0.407484
0.3918432
0.3822392
0.3803184
0.3860808
0.3998008
0.4181856
0.440412
0.4634616
0.4837672
0.5002312
0.510384
0.5128536
0.5065424
0.4933712
0.4752608
0.4522112
0.4297104
0.4080328
0.3912944
0.381416
0.3794952
0.3880016
0.3987032
0.4179112
0.4420584
0.4626384
0.4832184
0.499408
0.5125792
0.5128536
0.506268
0.4933712
0.4749864
0.45276
0.4297104
0.4091304
0.3926664
0.382788
0.3808672
0.3866296
0.3998008
0.41846
"""

ydata=[float(_) for _ in ydata.strip().splitlines()]
print(ydata)
def sin_fun(x,a,b,c,d):
    return a*np.cos(b*x+c)+d

p_opt,p_cov=cf(sin_fun,xdata,ydata, p0=(0.05, 0.5, 0.01,0.45),method='trf')

print(p_opt)
plt.plot(xdata,sin_fun(xdata,*p_opt))
plt.plot(xdata,ydata, 'r.-', ms=1)
plt.show()
```

I tried scaling the graph vertically and horizontally, but it seem to make things worse (the amplitude was now smaller than 0.05, not larger than it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing to understand about gradient-based optimizers like curve_fit is that they're very bad at fitting sine waves. Here is a plot of your objective function, while only varying b. The X axis represents the `b` parameter. The Y axis is the root mean square error of the fit, with lower values meaning a better fit.

[image: objective function]

The problem with curve_fit is that it's a local optimizer. Any local optimizer can get stuck in local optima, and a program that tries to fit a frequency parameter for sine wave will get stuck in lots of local optima. Any valley in the above function is a place where it can get stuck.

There are a few things you can try here.

1. Use a better guess.
2. Use a global optimizer.

Here's how to solve this by using a better initial guess.

I would suggest using an FFT to figure out what frequency to use.

Example:

```
fft = np.fft.fft(ydata - np.array(ydata).mean())
timestep = xdata[1] - xdata[0]
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(fft), d=timestep)
largest_component = np.abs(fft).argmax()
phase_guess = np.angle(fft[largest_component]) * freq[largest_component]
initial_frequency_guess = freq[largest_component] * 2 * np.pi


p0 = np.array([
    np.std(ydata) * np.sqrt(2),
    initial_frequency_guess,
    phase_guess,
    np.mean(ydata)
])
p_opt,p_cov=cf(sin_fun,xdata,ydata, p0=p0,method='trf')
```

The most important one is `initial_frequency_guess`. The optimizer can figure out the other ones.

Here is the fit this guess produces:

[image: guess]

Then polish it with `curve_fit()`:

[image: curve fit]

Comment: The objective function made it much more obvious what the problem is --- I estimated the frequency as `10`, thinking it was good enough. However, it is clear now that 'good enough' is not good enough for sine functions.

Comment: Could you also help with a dampened sine function --- something of the form `a*(np.e**(-x/e))*np.sin(b*x+c)+d`. I know that the frequency doesn't change (much), so I tried using the same FFT code for the frequency --- however, this time, the fitted amplitude was ~0.

Comment: @StarDust Sure. Post the data?

Comment: I posted it as a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77491622/15436715).

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer is---in general---correct, FFT or even global optimizer is not required for this data. The problem is the presence of local minima for non-linear optimization. Linear optimization does not have this problem. Fortunately one [can rewrite the problem into a linear one](https://www.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales) if the data is reasonably dense.

My approach would be:

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

###removing offset as mean 
mean = np.mean( ydata )
ydata = np.array( ydata ) - mean

### functions
def signal( t, w, a, b ):
    r = a * np.sin( w * t ) + b * np.cos( w * t )
    return r

def sig_phase( t, d, w, p, o ):
    return d * np.sin( w * t + p ) + o
    
### numerical integrals
Sl = cumtrapz( ydata, x=xdata, initial=0 )
SSl = cumtrapz( Sl, x=xdata, initial=0 )

### fitting the integro-differential equation
VMXT = np.array( [ ydata, xdata , np.ones( len( xdata ) ) ] )
VMX = VMXT.transpose()

A = np.dot( VMXT, VMX )
SV = np.dot( VMXT, SSl )
AI = np.linalg.inv( A )
result = np.dot( AI , SV )
print ( "Fit: ",result )
w = np.sqrt(-1/result[0])
print( "w = ", w )

### putting offset back
ydata = ydata + mean 

### Fitting the linear parameters
VMXT = np.array( [ np.sin( w * xdata ), np.cos( w * xdata ),  np.ones( len( xdata ) )  ] )
VMX = VMXT.transpose()

A = np.dot( VMXT, VMX )
SV = np.dot( VMXT, ydata )
AI = np.linalg.inv( A )
a, b, d = np.dot( AI , SV )
print ("A = ", a, "B = ", b, "D = ", d )

### calculating alternative parameters
phi = np.arctan( b / a )
c = np.sqrt( a * a + b * b )

### Non-linear fit using previous results
sol, error = curve_fit( sig_phase, xdata, ydata, p0=[ c, w, phi, d ] )

### fitted graphs 
ylf = signal( xdata, w, a, b ) + d
ynl = sig_phase( xdata, *sol )

### plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot( xdata, ydata, ls='',  marker='x', label="data" )
ax.plot( xdata, ylf , label="linear")
ax.plot( xdata, ynl, label="non-linear" )
plt.legend( loc=0)
plt.show()
```

The linear fit is already very good, but gets slightly improved by the non-linear one.

[image: fit comparison]

Comment: Interesting... I can't access the scribd paper --- is there some other place where I can read it?

Comment: @StarDust maybe here? https://scikit-guess.readthedocs.io/en/sine/_downloads/4b4ed1e691ff195be3ca73879a674234/Regressions-et-equations-integrales.pdf There is a second paper about discontinuous functions as well.